# Python - Kivy: KeyError with Text Input using ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy, user-input, keyerror

I'm working on a project using **Kivy** with **ScreenManager** (and **KivyMD**).

The reason for using this is my need of making an application with multiple screens. My goal is to get **User Input** from an existing **MDTextField** by *(a string)* **ID** and then **Print it out**.

However, I keep getting this **Error**: `File "<string>", line 37, in <module> File "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/myApp/Main.py", line 75, in loginFunction username = mainScreenInstance.ids["input_username"].text KeyError: 'input_username'`.

I have searched for answers all over the internet and StackOverflow, but no solution seems to work for me. Maybe there's someone who can help me with my problem and make my code work.

Anyway, here's my short & simple **Code**:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import sys

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager: 
    MenuScreen:
        name: 'menu'
    SecondScreen:
        name: 'second'

<MenuScreen>:
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Menu Screen"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        anchor_title: "center"
        md_bg_color: (0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1)
    Image:
        source: "Logo_h_black.png"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.75}
        size_hint_x: (0.25)
        size_hint_y: (0.25)
    MDTextField:
        id: input_username
        hint_text: "Username"
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.55}
        font_size: 20
        mode: "rectangle"
    MDTextField:
        id: input_password
        hint_text: "Password"
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.45}
        font_size: 20
        mode: "rectangle"
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "LOG IN"
        font_size: 17
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.25}
        on_press: app.loginFunction()
    
<SecondScreen>:
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Profile'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        

"""

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))


class myApp(MDApp):

    def loginFunction(self, args=None):          
                                                 
        if args is None:
           args = sys.argv

        mainScreenInstance = sm.get_screen('menu')

        username = mainScreenInstance.ids["input_username"].text
        password = mainScreenInstance.ids["input_password"].text

        print (username)
        print (password)

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

myApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `loginFunction` is trying to get the `mainScreenInstance` from `sm`, but `sm` is created before the `screen_helper` is loaded, so it doesn't know about the `ids` you have defined in your `screen_helper`. Also, that `sm` is not actually used as part of you GUI, it is just ignored (except for your reference to it in the `loginFunction`).

So, I recommend that you eliminate the following lines completely:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
```

And change `loginFunction` to not use `sm` by replacing:

```
mainScreenInstance = sm.get_screen('menu')
```

with:

```
mainScreenInstance = self.root.get_screen('menu')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're duplicating the widget definitions and then not using them in code. Finally, you're overwriting the Screen manager from the screen_helper string with a new instance. Tbh I did some of that when I started learning Kivy. The kv language is confusing at first but once you get it is beautiful. This version *should* work (I haven't tested it since I haven't found an easy way to install kivymd on my phone's dev env):

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import sys

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
        name: 'menu'
    SecondScreen:
        name: 'second'

<MenuScreen>:
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Menu Screen"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        anchor_title: "center"
        md_bg_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    Image:
        source: "Logo_h_black.png"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.75}
        size_hint_x: (0.25)
        size_hint_y: (0.25)
    MDTextField:
        id: input_username
        hint_text: "Username"
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.55}
        font_size: 20
        mode: "rectangle"
    MDTextField:
        id: input_password
        hint_text: "Password"
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.1)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.45}
        font_size: 20
        mode: "rectangle"
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "LOG IN"
        font_size: 17
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.25}
        on_press: app.loginFunction()
    
<SecondScreen>:
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Profile'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        

"""

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class myApp(MDApp):
    sm = None
    def on_start():
        self.sm = self.root

    def loginFunction(self, args=None):                       
        if args is None:
           args = sys.argv

        mainScreenInstance = self.sm.get_screen('menu')

        username = mainScreenInstance.ids["input_username"].text
        password = mainScreenInstance.ids["input_password"].text

        print (username)
        print (password)

        # if self.is_login_correct(username, password):
        #     self.sm.current('second') 

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen_helper) 

myApp().run()
```

Personally, I would move all login-related functions to the MenuScreen class, for consistency.